# Will the people, who end up in heaven, gain additional glory for each soul that profits from their writings?

Tags: catholicism, heaven, saint, afterlife, glory

Will the people, who end up in heaven, gain additional glory for each soul that profits from their writings?
For example, St. Augustine wrote many good books. Now he is in heaven. To this very day, people read his books and have spiritual benefits. Does St. Augustine receive additional beatitude in heaven for each soul that profits from his books? I want a Catholic answer.